# Record Historical Value and Compare Values of Numerical field

Tags: reporting, history-tracking, field-history, analytic-snapshots

I have a numerical field called Score on Account Object. This value changes frequently. For any given account I would like to be able to calculate the delta between the change between different time periods. e.g. Score at the Start of Week - Score at the End of Week = Change this week for an account. Possible?

Comment: unfortunately, historical trend reporting is not available on Account so Analytic Snapshots are the way to go